# HTTP 500 - couldn’t find file ‘vendor-bundle’ on sharetribe opensoure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sharetribe

After creating a dev instance of sharetribe, i got the following http error when hitting local host on port 3000 after “setup your market place”. Any tips on this error would be appreciated.

> INFO
>   {“method”:“GET”,“path”:"/",“format”:“html”,“controller”:“HomepageController”,“action”:“index”,“status”:500,“duration”:496.91,“view”:0.0,“db”:45.37,“params”:{},“host”:“0.0.0.0”,“community_id”:1,“current_user_id”:"",“user_agent”:“Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/55.0”,“referer”:"",“forwarded_for”:"",“request_uuid”:“522df877-291c-41b3-b286-53ca311e9dd8”}
>   FATAL ActionView::Template::Error - couldn’t find file ‘vendor-bundle’
>   with type 'application/javascript’ Checked in these paths:
>       /home/administrator/sharetribe/app/assets/font-awesome-icons
>       /home/administrator/sharetribe/app/assets/images
>       /home/administrator/sharetribe/app/assets/javascripts
>       /home/administrator/sharetribe/app/assets/stylesheets
>       /home/administrator/sharetribe/vendor/assets/javascripts
>       /home/administrator/sharetribe/vendor/assets/stylesheets

Comment: No MCVE Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please read that link and make sure that the code you post in your question is minimal (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), complete (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and verifiable (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). JsFiddle links don't count as an MCVE. Without an MCVE in your question, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Hope this link https://gist.github.com/d2s/372b5943bce17b964a79 could be helpful! Please provide some more information in what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you execute this command?

```sh
foreman start -f Procfile.static
```

You could also launch it only

```sh
script/wait_for_server_js.sh && rails s -b 0.0.0.0

script/export_routes_js.sh && cd client && npm run build:dev:client

script/export_translations.sh && script/wait_for_routes_js.sh && cd client && npm run build:dev:server
```